# How to find number of element in an Array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to know that how can i find the number of element in the normal array in java. For example if i have an int array with size 10 and i have inserted only 5 element. Now, i want to check the number of element in my array? Below is the code for more clarification. Please help

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [] intArray = new int[10];
        char [] charArray = new char[10];

        int count = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<=5; i++) {

            intArray[i] = 5;    
            charArray[i] = 'a';


        }


        for(int j=0; j<=intArray.length; j++) {
            if(intArray[j] != null) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("int Array element : "+ count);
    }
```

Comment: Just add count in original loop.

Comment: maybe it is time to learn [Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Comment: @Vid -  Just to be clear, you don't want to alter the array, you just want to get back "5 elements out of 10 are null" kind of thing, right?

Comment: @Hayden don't see that part. Suppose you already have that array with size = 10 and element = 5.

Comment: @chancea I already know the List. But i don't want any alternative.

Comment: There is no such thing in Java as a "partially filled array."   The entire array is filled; it's just that some elements may still be set to the default.

Comment: int[] can only contain ints (by default set to 0)... int[i] != null will always return true. You could use Integer[], but then you're better off using a List<Integer>.

Comment: @Ascalonian Yes, i just want number of element in array. Answer should be 6.

Comment: @Vid - Excellent! Check out my answer below then :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out `Collection.frequency()`. This will count how many times the specific Object (in this case `null`) appears in the Collection.

Below is just an example to help you along

```
String[] array = new String[5];

array[0] = "This";
array[1] = null;
array[2] = "is";
array[3] = null;
array[4] = "a test";

int count = Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(array), null);

System.out.println("String: " + count + " items out of " + array.length + " are null");

int[] iArray = new int[3];
iArray[0] = 0;
iArray[1] = 1;
iArray[2] = 2;

List<Integer> iList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i : iArray) {
    iList.add(i);
}

int iCount = Collections.frequency(iList, 0);

System.out.println("Int: " + iCount + " items out of " + iArray.length + " are zero");

char[] cArray = new char[3];
cArray[0] = 'c';
cArray[1] = ' ';
cArray[2] = 'a';

List<Character> cList = new ArrayList<>();

for (char c : cArray) {
    cList.add(c);
}

int cCount = Collections.frequency(cList, ' ');

System.out.println("Char: " + cCount + " items out of " + cArray.length + " are ' '");
```

Output:

> String: 2 items out of 5 are null 
>   Int: 1 items out of 3 are zero 
>   Char: 1 items out of 3 are ' '

Comment: Working with string array but not with int or char.

Comment: Since int and char are primitive, you cannot check for `null`. What would be your criteria to check on those?

Comment: for int it can be 0 and for char ' ', but not working.

Comment: @Vid - Added the int and char example code for you as well. need to convert into a `List` first on those, since they are primitive

Answer (score 8):

The code is wrong. You declare a `int[]` : this cannot contain null values so this statement will not compile :

```
if(intArray[j] != null) {
```

Then, if you want to store many items but you don't know howmany, you should use a `Collection`, for example `ArrayList`

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //Or new ArrayList<>(); - Java7
```

Then, you can have the size with :

```
ints.size();
```

Now, if you *really* want to use an array, then you can for example count the number of non-zero values :

```
for(int j=0; j<=intArray.length; j++) {
  if(intArray[j] != 0) {
    count++;
  }
}
```

Or better in **Java 7** :

```
for(int i : intArray) {
  if(i!=0) {
    count++;
  }
}
```

Even better in **Java 8** :

```
Arrays.stream(intArray).filter(i -> i !=0).count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change your first loop to something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<=5; i++) {
     intArray[i] = 5;    
     charArray[i] = 'a';
     count++;
}
```

Or better yet, instead of using an array use an ArrayList. Here is an example of how arraylists work.

```
ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Character> charList = new ArrayList<Character>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    intList.add(5);
    charList.add('a');
}
System.out.println("int list element : " + intList.size());
```

ArrayList's are dynamic and `.size()` will only return the size of items currently in the arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement your own solution for counting elements in an array, you can always implement your own wrapper class with the `array` in it if you want to.

```
public class classWithArray {
    private int[] arr;
    private int count;        

    public classWithArray(int arrLength) {
        arr = new int[5];
        count = 0;
    }

    public void add(int num) {
        arr[count] = num;
        count++;
    }        

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public int getElement(int index) {
        return arr[index];
    }

    // Add other wrapper methods.

}
```

You can make the `array` of a `Generic` type (I don't know much about `Java` for that though) to make it work for any data type.

Answer (score 0):

Well, We can use count  for non-zero elements in the array,The Code is Below::

```
public class SomeElementOfArrayUsingCount{

public static void main(String[] args){

     double total;//The sum of non-zero numbers in the Array.
     total=0;
     double average;//The average of non-zero numbers.
     int i;
     double count;//The number of non-zero numbers.
     count = 0;
     int[] list;
     list = new int[5];//make a container of 5.
     list[0]=2;
     list[1]=4;
     list[2]=4;
     list[3]=5;
     list[4]=2;

   for(i=0;i<list.length;i++){
       if(list[i]!=0){
           total = total + list[i];//Add element to the array
           count = count + 1;//and Count it
       }
   }

   if(count==0){
       System.out.println("There were no non-zero elements");
   }

   else {
       average = total/count;//Divide by number of items
       System.out.println("The average is " + average + " the total count is " + count);
   }
      } 
     }
```

Answer (score -3):

sysout();
This will help in your processes because it will print out the answer to what you are looking for.